# SSRS Remove Decimal when 100%

Tags: reporting-services, decimal, percentage

In my bar graphs, I would like to show my percentage with 2 decimal places when the results is less than 100%, but no decimal places when it is 100%. What do I need to do to get these results?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the formatting required to be put in the custom format expression.

=iif(Sum(Fields!Field_Name.Value) = 1, "###%", "#.00%")

Comment: You could also use `"P0"` and `"P2"` respectively which are the standard percentage formats